# Is there a difference between i==0 and 0==i?

Tags: c#, php, c++, c

First code:

```
  if(i==0) {// do instructions here}
```

Second code:

```
  if(0==i) { // do instructions here }
```

What is the difference between the blocks?

Comment: One won't have you spending time debugging because you forgot a `=`.

Comment: ... in the context of which language?

Comment: You're at least safe from the `if (i=0) {}` problem if you're using c#, since that syntax is illegal.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer: That isn't a problem in C#.

Comment: @alex Seriously this is the best comment, I've ever read :)

Comment: The compiler catches that in C#

Comment: @KendallFrey it is a valid expression in C++, so there is nothing for the compiler to catch.

Comment: And yet, @Juan, some C++ compilers catch it anyway. There it's a quality-of-implementation issue.

Comment: If you overloaded the == operator (not possible in all listed languages) you could make A == B different from B == A (not that you *should*, but you *can*).

Comment: reopened - the linked duplicate was weak, and this question has a good answer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference.
Some developers prefer writing the second format to avoid assignment typos(in case you miss a `=`), so that compiler warns of the typo.
The second is famously known as **[Yoda Condition](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)**.

[image: Yoda Condition]

I say there is no difference because, you cannot guard yourself against every minuscule detail and rely on compiler to cry out aloud for you.If you intend to write a `==` you should expect yourself to write a `==` and not a `=`.
 Using the second format just leads to some obscure non-readable code.
Also, most of the mainstream compilers warn of the *assignment* instead of *equality* typo by **[emitting an warning](http://ideone.com/Qk3Dd)** once you enable all the warnings(which you should anyways).

Comment: Its too bad they didn't put a historical lock on the [jargon question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined)

Comment: +1 for Yoda Condition & Pokemon Exception Handling.  Never heard those terms before.

Comment: @ConradFrix: Not only did they lock it, it has been deleted and now only 10k+ users can see it.

Comment: @JohnDibling that was kinda my point I wouldn't mind see that question revived via an [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/148672)

Comment: Indeed, it's a prime candidate for historical lock. Deleting it was inappropriate and accomplished nothing of value.

Comment: "Some developers" == "Amateurs" :)

Answer (score 7):

The second version is supposed to be safer.

In case you forget one equal sign, it does not change the value of i to zero.

Answer (score 5):

Functionally, they are the same in C; I'm not sure about other languages where ugly things like operator overloading come into play.

Stylistically, the latter is extremely counter-intuitive and personally I find it extremely ugly. The point is to get the compiler to throw an error when you accidentally write `=` instead of `==`, but good compilers have an option to warn you about this anyway so it's unnecessary.

Comment: Operator overloading is beautiful! (When applied correctly.) That's one of the things I love about C++, again and again.

Answer (score 3):

For C++, it's possible, though unlikely, that there could be a difference.  It depends upon what i's type is.  e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

bool operator==(Foo lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs;
}

bool operator==(int lhs, Foo rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Hi!";
    return true;
}
```

Someone who writes code like that should of course be shot.

Answer (score 2):

Yep they are same as far as C# is concerned.
For more complex situations visit [A==B vs B==A, What are the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878563/a-b-vs-b-a-what-are-the-differences)

Answer (score 1):

When you write (0==i) the error of using single equal to sign by mistake (e.g. ) if ( i = 0) is eliminated. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

no difference, some people prefer the second one to catch the common mistake of doing 
assignment (`=`) instead of equality test (`==`)

`0 = i` would fail at compilation

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is no difference. However in C++ there was a difference in performance which is why you see both used in C# code these days - actually I'm thinking of i++ vs ++i about performance - 0 == i is a common coding recommendation in C/C++ to avoid i = 0 as an accidental operation