# Efficiency ? any difference between these codes ?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between i==0 and 0==i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656419/is-there-a-difference-between-i-0-and-0-i)

What's the benefit of the following coding styles , is there any difference between them ?

```
int i;

// more code



if (i == 0) {...}
```

vs

```
if (0 == i) {...}
```

Thanks

Comment: One is easily readable.. the other one is none..

Comment: No, and the second style is called "Yoda conditional."

Comment: A comparison is a comparison when its this simple.

Comment: So from my understanding , the only goal of the `2nd` style is `defensive programming` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference, pick one and stick with it for consistency. The `(value == variable)` is a relic from older languages where you could accidentally assign a value to a variable in an if `(a = 0)`, instead of `(a == 0)`

They will both turn into (effectively) the same machine instruction, so there won't be any performance difference at all

Comment: It's not possible to assign a value in an if statement in Java?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity The question is also tagged as 'c'

Comment: So it is!  In that case this answer is wrong, specifically this part: `is a relic from older languages where you could accidentally assign a value to a variable in an if (a = 0), instead of (a == 0)`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity you're right, but in C and C++ it is possible, so this convention was used there. The convention migrated to other languages, even though it wasn't needed. Most modern compilers will give you a warning about this now anyway, but it's definitely a code-style issue, and not a performance one.

Comment: It was a legit question, because I was under the impression that it IS possible to assign in an if statement in Java.  And I found the implication that it wasn't possible to do that in Java to be surprising, but I wasn't totally sure, so I asked first. :)

Comment: Modern compilers, even for C and C++, will give compile warnings on accidental assignments like that.  (Clang specifically comes to mind; gcc -Wall does it, too.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - so did you try it **before asking**???

Answer (score 3):

No difference at all.

I've always found the latter example less readable, and I rarely see it, but some folks seem to like it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in efficiency, but this style is preferred for readability:

```
if (i == 0) {...}
```

The other version, `if (0 == i) {...}` is an example of a [Yoda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/201359), and it's considered a bad programming practice. Quoting from the link:

> "Yoda Conditions"— using if (constant == variable) instead of if (variable == constant), like if (4 == foo). Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or "if tall is the man".

[image]

Comment: FYI, your link is a removed post and not visible to users under 10k rep