# Null/Object and Null/Null comparison efficiency

Tags: java

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143549/java-null-check-syntactical-difference/17144070#17144070) lead me to do some testing:

```
public class Stack
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object obj0 = null;
        Object obj1 = new Object();
        long start;
        long end;
        double difference;  
        double differenceAvg = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                if (obj0 == null);

            end = System.nanoTime();
            difference = end - start;
            differenceAvg +=difference;
        }

        System.out.println(differenceAvg/100);
        differenceAvg = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                if (null == obj0);

            end = System.nanoTime();
            difference = end - start;
            differenceAvg +=difference;
        }

        System.out.println(differenceAvg/100);
        differenceAvg = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                if (obj1 == null);

            end = System.nanoTime();
            difference = end - start;
            differenceAvg +=difference;
        }

        System.out.println(differenceAvg/100);
        differenceAvg = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                if (null == obj1);

            end = System.nanoTime();
            difference = end - start;
            differenceAvg +=difference;
        }

        System.out.println(differenceAvg/100);      
    }
}
```

[image]

Tangential to the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143549/java-null-check-syntactical-difference/17144070#17144070), it's interesting to note how much faster the comparison is when the `Object` that we're comparing is initialized.  The first two numbers in each output are when the `Object` was `null` and the latter two numbers are when the `Object` was initialized.  I ran 21 additional executions of the program, in all 30 executions, the comparison was much faster when the `Object` was initialized.  What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting, one would expect it to work the other way around.

Comment: I'm running Java 7.11.  I figured it would be the other way around, too.

Comment: On my machine: 19383.09 / 51680.51 / 58.99 /62.51 (JDK 6)

Comment: @fge, it seems like it should be the opposite, right?

Comment: On JDK 7 however, it looks more like your results: 44742.84 / 51289.38 / 22.69 / 24.41 (note the difference of the first case compared to JDK 6)

Comment: @SteveP. yes, that would be logical...

Comment: I added a test by curiosity to compare reference equality of two objects: 23.85 (JDK 7), 24.29 (JDK 6); curiously, second run in JDK 6 was more like JDK 7 on the null test cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move last two loops to the beginning you will get the same results, so comparisons are irrelevant.

It's all about JIT compiler warm-up. During the first 2 loops `java` starts with interpreting bytecode. After some iterations, it determines that code path is "hot", so it compiles it to machine code and removes the loops that have no effect, so you are basically measuring `System.nanotime` and `double` arithmetic.

I'm not really sure why two loops are slow. I think that after it finds two hot paths it decides to optimize entire method.

Comment: When I put the last two loops in front, the results are a,b,c,d, where a,b,c>>d.

Comment: @SteveP. Are you sure you did it correctly, with `differenceAvg = 0;` where necessary?